# Silent push notification for certain user

Tags: ios, push-notification

i have an application that receive push notifications, i would like to implement a user settings profile with a "silent notification for x hours".

How can i prevent the sound of the notification? there's a something on a server or in a client?

Because now i can prevent the sound if the app is in foreground or background, but if the app is suspended how can i intercept and lock the sound and the notification?

Somethings like whatsapp or telegram application!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Upload the user settings to the server and ensure that the server doesn't send any push notification during the silent hours. During that time if the user opens the app they should be able to download the content but they shouldn't be notified about any new content when the app isn't already open.

Comment: thanks, i'm developing in this way, I was wondering if there was a way without interacting with sever!

Comment: preventing the server from sending the push is the best option for multiple reasons, not least of which is utilisation of resources and client simplicity.

Comment: Don't forget your server will need to store the timezone of the device for each user in addition to what the silent hours are.